# YII search is not working when renderPartial from another page

Tags: php, search, filter, yii, cgridview

I have a problem with Yii search, which is working fine when accessing the page(Students/admin) directly, but if i renderPartial the same page from another page(Students/reg), Yii filter not search the result..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yii search in CGridView is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the model manually in your `actionReg` of the `StudentsController`. These values of the model will be used by the `CGridView` to set the filter.

This might be something like this:

```
public function actionReg($id) {
  $model = Students::model();
  $model->attributes = $_GET['Students'];

  $this->render('reg', array(
           'model' => $model,
        ));
}
```

If you have custom values in the model you have to set them also, for example

```
  $model->calculatedAverage = $_GET['Students']['calculatedAverage'];
```

Then in your `RegView` you can pass this model to the table.

To get an idea of how this works, try understanding what happens in the `adminAction` method.

Comment: Thnx Man, its works for me.. And i need to learn more.. thanx alot

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting this right, renderPartial doesn't process inline js if you don't use it properly. Try doing:

```
$this->renderPartial('view',array(...),false,true);
```

It should help. The last argument (**true**), tells Yii to process output.

Comment: thx alot kapo, my code for renderPartial, given here.. i use this in CGridview.. the page display the datas and other functionalities were working good. except search 
     
    array('id' => 'tab1','label'=>'Manage', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('//Students/admin', array('model'=>$model,), true ), 'active' => true,),

Comment: I can't understand where you're using this array('id'=>...). In the controller? I can't help you without seeing some bigger piece of code

Comment: $tabs=array(     
    array('id'=>'tab1','label'=>'Manage', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('//Students/admin', array('model'=>$model,), true, true ), 'active' => true,),
    array('id'=>'tab4','label'=>'Add Students', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('create',array('model'=>$model,'medicalinfo'=>$medicalinfo,'parent'=>$parent,'royalty'=>$royalty,'worksheet'=>$worksheet), true)),
   array('id'=>'tab3','label'=>'2012', 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('adminold', array('model'=>$model1,), true)),);
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
'type'=>'pills', 
'id' => 'tabs',
'tabs'=> $tabs,

Comment: im using this under 'bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs'

Comment: the guy here has the similar problem to yours:
http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8275

It's in russian, but what he does, is using renderPartial(...,false,true);

Comment: I tried it, if i use false, true in that place, my tab will disappear and still having the problem, filter cant search.. should i need anything others to change ??